# Drop GST_EVENT_EOS on a rtspsrc connection

Tags: rust, gstreamer, gstreamer-rs

I am implementing a Gstreamer pipeline in rust to ingest rtsp feed from different cameras. I use the `hlssink2` element to create manifest to view/store the video.

For some of the cameras, the hlssink2's splitmux element receives a `GST_EVENT_EOS` which results in the pipeline stopping.

This happens even if I add a `bus.add_watch` and capture the `gst::MessageView::Eos(state_changed)` event.

Is there a way to programatically block the EOS message and keep the rtsp connection on?

Can I add a `add_probe` to one of the elements pads and make it ignore it? Something like the following? But I am not sure which element should I do it on and what the implications would be?

```
<rtsp element's video pad>.add_probe(gst::PadProbeType::BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, |_pad, _info| {
                gst::PadProbeReturn::Ok
            }).unwrap();
```

Here is an example pipeline for which I have a rust implementation.

```
gst-launch-1.0 hlssink2 name=ingest1 playlist-length=5 max-files=0 target-duration=10 \
send-keyframe-requests=true playlist-location=/tmp/manifest.m3u8 location=/tmp/video/%t.ts \
rtspsrc latency=100 location=<rtspurl> protocols=0x00000004 name=basesrc basesrc. ! rtph264depay ! tee name=t \
t.! queue  ! ingest1.video
```

Comment: I tried using errorignore and set the ignore-eos flag. I set this in after rtspsrc and right before hlssink2. But the EOS seems to be detected by splitmuxsink inside hlssink2.